# Differentiate $y=4\,e^{\cos2x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I do not know what to do for this question
$$ y=4\,e^{\cos2x}$$
Can anyone show me or give me an example?

I think I should be using the chain rule but not $100\%$ sure how to break up the question.

Answer (score 4):

The chain rule says that the derivative of a function like $$f(g(x))$$ is $$f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)$$. In your particular question, let $$f(x)=4e^x$$ and $$g(x)=\cos(2x)$$. Then differentiate just as usual.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT :**

Let $u=2x$, $v=\cos u$, and $w=e^v$, then by chain rule
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{\color{blue}{dv}}\cdot\frac{\color{blue}{dv}}{\color{red}{du}}\cdot\frac{\color{red}{du}}{dx}.
$$

Comment: i didn't think of breaking it up mor than twice >.< many thanks

Comment: @John You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Another way that may save you a bit of effort: log both sides to get
$$
\log f(x) = \log 4 + \cos 2 x
$$
Now differentiate both sides to get 
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = -2 \sin 2x
$$
and obviously 
$$
f'(x) = -2 f(x) \sin 2x
$$

Answer (score 0):

You're quite right you should be using the chain rule: look at it this way: $4e^x=f(x)$, $cos(x) = g(x)$ and $2x = h(x)$. Now differentiate $f(g(h(x)))$ using the chain rule. We obtain $f'(g(h(x)) \frac{d g(h(x))}{dx} = f'(g(h(x)) g'(h(x))h'(x) =4 e^{\cos(2x)} \times -\sin(2x) \times 2 = -8\sin(2x) e^{\cos(2x)}.$
So as you can see we use the chain rule 2 times!

Comment: y = 4 e^(cos 2x) 
y' = 4 e^(cos 2x) d/dx ( cos 2x) 
y' = 4 e^(cos 2x) ( - sin 2x) d/dx (2x) 
y' = 4 e^(cos 2x) (- sin 2x) (2) 
y' = -8 e^(cos 2x) sin 2x thats what i got but tossed it away because i thought it was wrong lol

Comment: It's correct :D. It is good to be critical though.